# Can a file appear to be modified before it was created?

Tags: metadata, file-attributes

Is it possible to have a file which has a modified date that is before its created date? What actions would cause this event to occur?

Comment: Create the file. Turn back the clock. Modify the file. Put the clock back again.

Comment: @DavidPostill Note that, at least on Windows, changing the system time requires administrative privileges, while there are other ways of creating funny file times that don't.

Comment: This is not a duplicate at all. The linked duplicate is about whether creation time can be manually modified by a user, and this question is about what the definitions of "creation time" and "modified time" are.

Answer (score 20):

If you create a file from scratch, it gets a creation time of "now", and a modification date of "now". Now imagine copying this file to another drive. Windows will keep the modification time, but the creation time of that file will be set to the time you copied the file to that drive (i.e. the time the file was created on *that* drive). Simple as that.

It’s actually correct:

- The last time the contents of the file were changed is stored in the modification time.
- The time the file was created on this very drive is stored in the creation time.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, it's very easy to set (falsify, if you will) a file's created and modified times. You don't have to change the computer's clock; you don't even need local admin access. All you need is write access to the file in question.

To set a file's creation time with PowerShell using [`SetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[System.IO.File]::SetCreationTime("C:\path\to\file.ext", (Get-Date "8/8/2088"))
```

To set the last-modified time using [`SetLastWriteTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[System.IO.File]::SetLastWriteTime("C:\path\to\file.ext", (Get-Date "7/4/1776"))
```

On Linux, you can easily change a file's last-modified time with the `-d` flag of `touch`, as shown in [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/62496/476938). There isn't really a notion of a creation date for files on Linux file systems ([further reading at Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102692)).

Answer (score 8):

Consider a .tar archive that is extracted. Typically the extracted files will have a last modification timestamp assigned from the archive contents (which is typically in the past unless you are a time traveller). As far as the filesystem is concerned, these files have just been created though.

There also exist utilities to change the modification time of existing files, on Linux for example this is the [touch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) command.

Comment: And for a single file, `cp -p` and things that imitate it like `rcp -p` and `scp -p`, as well as `rsync` with `-t` or `-a`, takes the modtime from the source.

Comment: "creation time" is a windows term not a *nix one. *nix has "change time" which is easy to confuse with "creation time" but not the same thing.

Comment: ext4 apparently does store a "birth time" which is similar to (but not the same as) the windows "creation time" but there is no good way to access it. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50184/122182

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  On Windows, make a change to the file and save it.  Now copy the file.  Looking at the properties of the copy, you'll see it has an earlier modified date.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to note here is that file modification time isn't really special - it's stored just like any other data. There's no way to tell when data was *actually* last written to, or read from.

From here, we can see that it's always possible (excluding write-once media like a CD) to go and directly modify the bits on a drive that store the last modified time, or even the creation time.

More practically, this is also doable from within common operating systems, as other answers have noted. In Windows, this is provided by the WinAPI [`SetFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933.aspx) function, and you can do this with [`utime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html) on Linux. Tools like `touch` build on top of these APIs.

The most common legitimate use for these APIs is in preserving modification time, e.g. when copying files, extracting them from archives, etc..

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is has been when one or more computers have been used to modify the file and one of them has the wrong system time.  The three most common causes for the system time being wrong, in no particular order are:

1. Not all computers are configured to automatically change to daylight savings time.
2. People have "accidentally" changed the system time on a computer.
3. People have "deliberately" changed the system time on a computer as a joke.